# Meta tags are inconsistently writing "Stack Exchange" with or without a space in their names

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta

On Meta, here are some tags:

- [stack-exchange](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange)
- [stack-exchange-button](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-button)
- [stack-exchange-openid](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-openid)
- [stack-exchange-team](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-team)
- [stackexchange-hq](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-hq)
- [stackexchange-filter](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-filter)
- [russian-stackexchange](/questions/tagged/russian-stackexchange)
- [stackexchange-tour](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-tour)
- [stackexchange-2.0](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-2.0)

etc.

These tags don't agree on if "Stack Exchange" is one or two words. "Stack Overflow"-related tags have the same problem.

**Can these please be made consistent, mods?**